# GUI elements in (Dr) Racket

Tags: user-interface, button, canvas, racket

I need some basic stuff for working with the GUI library in Racket.

1. How do I set the callback function to a button like this:

   ```
   (define next (new button% [parent frame] [label "Next ->"]))
   ```
2. How do I draw something on a canvas after it's been created like this:

   ```
   (define canvas (new canvas% [parent frame]  
       [paint-callback canvasdc]))

   (define canvasdc (lambda (canvas dc)  
       (send dc set-text-foreground "black")  
       (send dc draw-text "Some title!" 0 0)  
   ))
   ```

   I would need to draw (rescaled jpegs or, if not able) compound shapes and repaint with something else on every button pressed event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There's an optional `callback` argument to the button constructor.
2. See http://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/overview.html. But I'm confused by your question since the code you've posted *includes* drawing to the canvas. For images, specifically, `read-bitmap` will read a bitmap from a file; `draw-bitmap` will draw a bitmap into a DC. You can get it (along with all other drawing to that DC) scaled by calling `set-scale`. If the DC you're drawing into is a `bitmap-dc` (I don't *think* a `canvas-dc` is, but I am not a Racket expert and could be wrong) then you can do it directly using `draw-bitmap-section-smooth`.

Comment: Thanks. And how is the callback argument called?  And how do I redraw the canvas? This is unclear to me.

Comment: The callback gets two arguments: the button object and an event object. I think it only gets called when the button is clicked, so you can ignore the event argument (unless you care what button it was clicked with, I guess). You can draw things on the canvas DC at any time and the system will update the screen shortly afterwards. There's a `flush` method that forces the update to happen immediately, if you need that, and a `refresh-now` method that forces the canvas's paint callback to be called and then (optionally) a flush to be done. Disclaimer repeat: I am not a Racket expert.

Comment: Thanks again. I got it now. Your response was of great help